# Android-Java HTTPCLIENT send http parameters with Content-Disposition image uploading

Tags: java, php, android, httpclient

I have a image uploader function in java using HttpClient and I'm using Content-Disposition for it. 
But I'm stuck there I did not realize how can i insert another body form paramaters in this post request.
For example I want to add a paramaters like:

```
description = "my image's description"
```

My Code :

```
File file = new File(filepath);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        URL url = new URL(UPLOAD_SERVER);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Multipart HTTP Client 1.0");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);
        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.writeBytes("--" + boundary + "\r\n");
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + "img_upload" + "\"; filename=\"" + q[idx] +"\"" + "\r\n");
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/jpeg" + "\r\n");
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + "\r\n");
        outputStream.writeBytes("\r\n");
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, 1048576);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while(bytesRead > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, 1048576);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        outputStream.writeBytes("\r\n");
        outputStream.writeBytes("--" + boundary + "--" + "\r\n");
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        int status = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            connection.disconnect();
            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            return response.toString();
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Non ok response returned");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try doing this:

```java
outputStream.writeBytes("--" + boundary + "\r\n");
outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + "img_upload" + "\"; filename=\"" + q[idx] +"\"" + "\r\n");
outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/jpeg" + "\r\n");
outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + "\r\n");
outputStream.writeBytes("--" + boundary + "\r\n");
outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + "description" + "\"" + "\r\n");
outputStream.writeBytes("\r\n");
outputStream.writeBytes(description);
outputStream.writeBytes("--" + boundary + "\r\n");
```

Comment: Unfortu. did not work.

But what is description variable supposed to be in
outputStream.writeBytes(description);

Comment: @HalitKalayci it is the string in the beginning of the question: description = "my image's description"

Comment: Thanks for your help lucas, it works. I was misspelled something and i managed to fixed it.
Thanks again.